# Why do I need to persist the owning side of relationship?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Consider this piece of code: This is from Repository class and I've properly annotated class with @Transactional.

```
public void addSubjectsToStudents(int studentId, List<Subject> subjects) {

    // 1. retrieve subject
    Student student = findById(studentId);

    // 2. add students
    subjects.forEach(subject -> {

        // 2.1 subjects are new -> so first persist them
        em.persist(subject);

        // 2.1 add student to subject
        subject.addStudent(student);

        // 2.2 add subject to student
        // must do both 2.1 and 2.2 because ManyToMany relationship
        student.addSubject(subject);
    });

    // this is newly added line here: why do I need to persist student ?
    // now persist the owning side
    em.persist(student);
}
```

Now when I ran the code without the last line, the tests are working fine without any error. But on the database side, nothing is updated.

Then I looked into the tutorial and found out that I had to persist the owning side...

Now why is this? I am retrieving Student (owning side) from database and therefore it is tracked by EntityManager (I have added @PersistenceContext to em)

Hence I only need to persist newly added subject beforehand. At this point: both subjects and student would be managed automatically by EntityManager. So I don't need to persist anything anymore.

But it seems my  thoughts are wrong in this matter. This only happens when in @ManyToMany relationship. In other types, this problem didn't occur.

What am I missing here? I've looked into similar problems and nobody explained the why part.

I have omitted additional code for brevity. Feel free to request if you need those pieces of code for Repository and Entities. But, I have added everything by the tutorial and other cases have successfully passed except this one.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, a `@ManyToMany` relationship between two entity classes will be implemented under the hood using *three* SQL tables.  Each of the two entities will have its own table, *and* there will be a third *junction* table which maps primary keys from one entity to primary keys from the other entity.  It is because of this junction table that there needs to be an object-to-object relationship between the two entities in Java.  This allows Hibernate/JPA to figure out which tuple needs to be inserted in the junction table.

Comment: I have already added #JoinTable and #JoinColumns to both entities. Shouldn't hibernate know that when it initially started to track Student entity that there is another table it has to update? I don't understand

Comment: I get your doubts.  I don't have a better answer than what I posted above.  Hibernate appears to define a 2 way relationship as...a 2 way relationship.  That is, both entities have to be pointing to each other in order for it to work.

Comment: I think perhaps your answer may be incorrect. I've tried the other way around and it didn't work even when I persist both parties of the relationship. I have added it here, please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70494629/the-non-owning-part-of-manytomany-relationship-seems-to-not-work-when-trying-to

Comment: @ahrooran ... and I saw that question and the code has a lot of problems.  I'm 100% certain that if you properly set both sides of the relationship it works.